# What data structure would this pseudo-code represent or act upon?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, pseudocode

I have some pseudo-code that I am trying to label. Here it is:

```
a= head
while a.value < b.value do a = a.next
b.next = a.next
a.next = b
```

To me this appears to be code used on a singly, or doubly linked list, but I have at least confirmed that it is NOT as doubly linked list. Does anyone know what data structure this would be from or act upon? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for a singly-linked list. It looks like a routine to insert a node `b` into a list in sorted order. The chain of `next` links and lack of `prev` links are highly indicative of a singly-linked list. If this routine does what I think it does, though, it appears bugged; it doesn't seem to handle the case where `b`'s value is greater than all values in the list.

Comment: Ok, so what sets this apart from a doubly-linked list is that a is specified as the "head" whereas in a doubly linked list this would not have to be specified? Is this correct?

Comment: @Turtle-in-a-bash-shell: No. The first two lines would be identical for a doubly-linked list. We can tell this isn't doubly-linked because for a doubly-linked list, the code would have to update the `prev` links corresponding to the `next` links it modifies.